# Conditionally change values of data.frame but keep everything else unchanged in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, if-statement, tidyverse

Below, I'm wondering how to only change values of my data according to the following condition:

if `ir== 2, "ESL"`, if `ir == 3, "EFL"`, if `ir == 1, "timed"`, if `ir == 0, "untimed"`

But I wonder how to keep everything else unchanged (i.e., ***keep the first 3 columns unchanged***)?

```
(ir <- data.frame(item=1:10,study.name = paste("Study", c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5)),
                 group.name = c(1,2,1,1,2,3,1,2,1,2),  
                 Time = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), 
                   Time.1 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0),
                   Setting = c(2, 2, rep(3, 8)),
                   Setting.1 = c(2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)))

# I have tried the following without success:

(ir1 <- data.frame(ifelse(ir== 2, "ESL", ifelse(ir == 3, "EFL", ifelse(ir == 1, "timed", "untimed")))))
```

Comment: Do you want to do that to every column? Or just one column? What do you want to leave unchanged? What is your desired output?

Comment: For all columns?

Comment: @Alexlok, except the first 3 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `recode` to change the values.

```
library(dplyr)

ir %>%
  mutate(across(-(1:3), ~recode(., "0"="untimed",
                               "1"="timed",
                               "2"="ESL",
                               "3"="EFL")))

#   item study.name group.name    Time  Time.1 Setting Setting.1
#1     1    Study 1          1   timed   timed     ESL       ESL
#2     2    Study 1          2 untimed untimed     ESL       ESL
#3     3    Study 2          1   timed   timed     EFL       EFL
#4     4    Study 3          1 untimed untimed     EFL       ESL
#5     5    Study 3          2   timed   timed     EFL       ESL
#6     6    Study 3          3 untimed untimed     EFL       ESL
#7     7    Study 4          1   timed   timed     EFL       EFL
#8     8    Study 4          2 untimed   timed     EFL       EFL
#9     9    Study 5          1 untimed   timed     EFL       EFL
#10   10    Study 5          2   timed untimed     EFL       EFL
```

Comment: Ronak, do you have a shorter solution to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65486367/7223434) as well?

Comment: I went through that question but unfortunately I don't have a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using a key dataframe and reshaping to long and wide using `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Keys
Keys <- data.frame(value=c(2,3,1,0),
                   char=c("ESL","EFL","timed","untimed"),
                   stringsAsFactors = F)
#Code
new <- ir %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(item,study.name,group.name)) %>%
  left_join(Keys) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=char)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 7
    item study.name group.name Time    Time.1  Setting Setting.1
   <int> <chr>           <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    
 1     1 Study 1             1 timed   timed   ESL     ESL      
 2     2 Study 1             2 untimed untimed ESL     ESL      
 3     3 Study 2             1 timed   timed   EFL     EFL      
 4     4 Study 3             1 untimed untimed EFL     ESL      
 5     5 Study 3             2 timed   timed   EFL     ESL      
 6     6 Study 3             3 untimed untimed EFL     ESL      
 7     7 Study 4             1 timed   timed   EFL     EFL      
 8     8 Study 4             2 untimed timed   EFL     EFL      
 9     9 Study 5             1 untimed timed   EFL     EFL      
10    10 Study 5             2 timed   untimed EFL     EFL
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `across()` and `switch()`. `across()` lets you specify a range of columns to which to apply a function. `switch()` takes an input and converts it depending on its value. You could also use `dplyr::case_when()`. Since `switch()` is not vectorized, I use `map()` to apply it to a whole column at once.

```
ir %>%
  mutate(across(Time:Setting.1,
                ~ map_chr(as.character(.x),
                          function(x) switch(x,
                                             "0"="untimed",
                                             "1"="timed",
                                             "2"="ESL",
                                             "3"="EFL"))))
```